# Finding if a trajectory is possible

Tags: calculus

So, I have two places. Point a and point b. What variables would I need, and how would I use them to find out if it was possible to shoot a gun from point a and hit point b (With the speed and accuracy of the gun being a constant, although the accuracy of the gun not being 100%)

Comment: I don't think accuracy is relevant. If there is any uncertainty at all, you will almost certainly not hit a given mathematical point exactly, but it may still be "possible" to hit that point.  What is relevant:
are you taking air resistance into account, and if so how?

Comment: As this is for a video game, no, I am not accounting for air resistance. And if accuracy does not matter, so be it. And I should have been clearer, I mean hit within the general vicinity of point B, as I am describing a video game character as point B.

Comment: If one ignore air resistance, the safety zone is bounded by a parabola (it is called [parabola of safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola_of_safety)). Look at answers of this [question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/30402/33248) for a start.

Comment: Although that does help a bit, I still do not see how I can derive an answer, which, in this case, would be true or false.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation system is 
$$\eqalign{\ddot{x} &= 0\cr
           \ddot{y} &= -g\cr}$$
where $g$ is the acceleration of gravity.  Solutions are
$$ \eqalign{x &= x_0 + u_0 t\cr
          y &= y_0 + v_0 t - g t^2/2\cr}$$
where the initial conditions are 
$$\eqalign{x(0) &= x_0\cr y(0) &= y_0\cr  \dot{x}(0) &= u_0\cr \dot{y}(0) &= v_0\cr}$$ 
Eliminating $t$ (assuming $u_0 \ne 0$), the trajectory is
$$ y = y_0 + \dfrac{v_0}{u_0} (x - x_0) - \dfrac{g (x - x_0)^2}{2 u_0^2}$$
Now if you want the initial point $(x_0, y_0) = a$ and  the final point to 
be $b = (x_1, y_1)$, you can plug that in for $(x,y)$.  The initial speed
(muzzle velocity) of the bullet is given: $w = \sqrt{u_0^2 + v_0^2}$, so that
$u_0 = w \cos(\theta)$, $v_0 = w \sin(\theta)$, where you aim upward at angle $\theta$.  After some simplification, this leads to
$$  (y_1 - y_0) \cos(2 \theta) + (x_0 - x_1) \sin(2\theta)
 = y_0- y_1 - \dfrac{g}{w^2} (x_0 - x_1)^2 $$ 
Now by adjusting $\theta$, we can make the left side anything from 
$-R$ to $R$, where $R = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2}$ is the distance from $a$ to $b$. So the condition to be able to hit $b$ from $a$ is

$$-R \le  y_0- y_1 - \dfrac{g}{w^2} (x_0 - x_1)^2  \le R$$
which turns out to be equivalent to
$$ y_1 - y_0 \le \dfrac{w^2}{2g} - \dfrac{g}{2w^2} (x_0 - x_1)^2 $$